# How to debug c++ file in vscode on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to debug `.cpp` file in vscode and following files have been installed perfectly. (I've ran `.cpp` file via `code-runner extension` but now I'd like to debug c++ files.)

```
$ clang --version // or g++ --version (both same result)

Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

And I've clicked the debug button and tried every compiler that listed

- `C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file`
- `C/C++: clang build and debug active file`
- `C/C++: g++ build and debug active file`
- `C/C++: cpp build and debug active file`

But on every try I've encountered following result:

```bash
Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

or an error message

```
The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++ build active file' terminated with exit code -1.
```

Is there another way that I can debug c++ file in vscode on macOS?

**My `tasks.json` file** (my c++ file is in the project root directory)

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**My `launch.json` file**

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the launch.json "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file" 
use task.json "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
as it's execute task 
so you launch.json should be modified 
notice change clang to clang++ to match task label

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I've just tried that but `Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.` error message comes still.. when I debug the file, it creates execuatblee file and it runs well! But I can't debug...

Comment: am I missing something?....

Comment: do you mean you can't input into the terminal or you don't make break point.It has been finished?

Comment: Oh I meant I can not give an input anywhere (Ive tried developer console, debug console...)

Comment: may be you need to set "externalConsole": true, to make input to terminal.